# Python -Flask не получается отправить POST запрос

Tags: python, flask

Есть две функции: одна отправляет данные в виде словаря ( допустим какую -то строку и два числа) , POST запрос. Другая функция принимает этот запрос. Все осуществляется с помощью Flask. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Что именно не получается? И же ваш код, которым вы пробовали это делать?

Comment: Я не понимаю, как это реализовать, пытаюсь сделать функцию с декоратором app.route и методом пост, но как принять этот запрос? Было бы славно увидеть пример кода

Comment: В документации по Flask разве нет примера обработки POST запроса?